# Which pots should I use to maximize my buffs?

Tags: fire-emblem-fates

In chapter 12 of Fire Emblem Fates (Conquest Route), there are dozens of pots liberally scattered about the map, half filled with "poison" and half filled with "medicine".

The in-game guide emphasizes that each pot has several different effects, but as I replay the level again and again (darn you, reinforcement archers!) trying to clear it, I've noticed that the pots seem to have the same buffs each time. (For instance, the medicine pot next to where Corrin starts gives +4 defense to all units within 2 tiles)

Is this randomized per-playthrough (unlikely) or are all the pot-breaking outcomes pre-determined? (I hope so!) If the latter, it seems like it'd be possible to plan a strategic pot-smashing strategy to avoid the worst of the poison (1/2 max HP) while maximizing the buff-tastic goodness of the medicines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an image with info on the pots credited to LfitLoyal.

[image]